# Efficient way to have Jackson serialize Java 8 Instant as epoch milliseconds?

Tags: json, spring, jackson, java-time

Using Spring RestControllers with Jackson JSON parsing backend, with AngularJS on front end.  I'm looking for an efficient way to have Jackson serialize an Instant as the epoch milliseconds for subsequent convenient usage with JavaScript code.  (On the browser side I wish to feed the epoch ms through Angular's [Date Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date): `{{myInstantVal | date:'short' }}` for my desired date format.)

On the Java side, the getter that Jackson would use is simply:

```
public Instant getMyInstantVal() { return myInstantVal; }
```

Serialization wouldn't work as-is, because the [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) doesn't return Epoch milliseconds by default for an Instant.  I looked at adding [@JsonFormat](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) to the above getter to morph the Instant into something the front-end can use, but it suffers from two problems: (1) the pattern I can supply it is apparently limited to SimpleDateFormat which doesn't provide an "epoch milliseconds" option, and (2) when I tried to send the Instant as a formatted date to the browser instead, Jackson throws an exception because the @JsonFormat annotation requires a TimeZone attribute for Instants, something I don't wish to hardcode as it would vary from user to user.

My solution so far (and it's working fine) is to create a replacement getter using [@JsonGetter](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations), which causes Jackson to use this method instead to serialize `myInstantVal`:

```
@JsonGetter("myInstantVal")
public long getMyInstantValEpoch() {
    return myInstantVal.toEpochMilli();
}
```

Is this the proper way of doing this?  Or is there a nice annotation I'm missing that I can put on getMyInstantVal() so I won't have to create these additional methods?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You just need to read the README that you linked to. Emphasis mine:

> **Most JSR-310 types are serialized as numbers (integers or decimals as appropriate) if the SerializationFeature#WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS feature is enabled**, and otherwise are serialized in standard ISO-8601 string representation.
>
> [...]
>
> Granularity of timestamps is controlled through the companion features SerializationFeature#WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS and DeserializationFeature#READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS. For serialization, timestamps are written as fractional numbers (decimals), where the number is seconds and the decimal is fractional seconds, if WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS is enabled (it is by default), with resolution as fine as nanoseconds depending on the underlying JDK implementation. **If WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS is disabled, timestamps are written as a whole number of milliseconds.**

Comment: I'm not sure how to set that value in the Spring XML config I'm using, I'm using Spring RestControllers and whatever default Jackson config it is using.  Researching further...

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean.html. But I would really avoid XML configuration. Java config is so much better.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this out.  No, I'm a stubbornly proud member of the XML config club.

Comment: How are the two other guys going? :-)

Comment: Also for those who use `spring-boot`: you can set any jackson features from `application.properties` file using `spring.jackson.*` prefix. For example, `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` serialization feature can be enabled using `spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=true` line. See more: [Appendix A. Common application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: In my opinion, this is a bad solution. It impacts every other `Instant` field you use that `ObjectMapper` for and if you use a different ObjectMapper (like in a unit tests) it won't take effect.

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me in Kotlin (should be the same for Java). This lets you serialize as an epoch millisecond without changing the ObjectMapper's configuration

```kotlin
data class MyPojo(
  @JsonFormat(without = [JsonFormat.Feature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS])
  val timestamp: Instant
)
```

Comment: The Java annotation syntax is slightly different; `without = {JsonFormat.Feature...}` with curly braces rather than square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

To apply for a single property, use this annotation:

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER, without = JsonFormat.Feature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
public Instant getMyInstantVal() { return myInstantVal; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to JB's answer, to override Spring MVC's default JSON parser to strip away the nanoseconds from Instant (and other Java 8 date objects that have them):

1. In the mvc:annotation-driven element, specify that you will be overriding the default JSON message converter:

   `<mvc:annotation-driven validator="beanValidator">
       <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
           <beans:ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
       </mvc:message-converters>
   </mvc:annotation-driven>`

(register-defaults above is [true](http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd) by default and most probably what you'll want to keep the other converters configured by Spring as-is).

2. Override MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter as follows:

   ```
   <beans:bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
   <beans:property name="objectMapper">
       <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
           <beans:property name="featuresToDisable">
               <beans:array>
                   <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS"/>
               </beans:array>
           </beans:property>
       </beans:bean>
   </beans:property>
   ```

Step #1 is important as Spring MVC will otherwise ignore the configured MJ2HMC object in favor of its own default one.

partial H/T [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650544/1207540) SO post.

Comment: Is there a non-XML solution of this?

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran Yup! https://stackoverflow.com/q/45762857/1207540

Answer (score 0):

1. JsonFormat Annotation:
   The point above regarding the @JsonFormat annotation is valid. But if you need to handle both serialization and deserialization, you may want to ensure that the configuration accommodates both aspects. The provided code snippet addresses the serialization part, but you might also need to configure deserialization.

> ```
> @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER, without = JsonFormat.Feature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
> public Instant getMyInstantVal() { return myInstantVal; }
> ```

2. the proposed spring boot autoconfiguration doesn't work:
   https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/1

In order to deserialize the millis, you can use a custom config :

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JsonDateTimeSerdeConfig {
    private final RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void handleContextRefresh() {
        handlerAdapter
                .getMessageConverters()
                .forEach(c -> {
                    if (c instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) c;
                        ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
                        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);
                    }
                });
    }
```

For sure it will affect all the timestamps in the service, but for me it would be strange to have different serde strategies in the same service.

Answer (score -2):

A simple way to return epoch millis in the JSON response for an Instant property can be following:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER, timezone = "UTC")
private Instant createdAt;
```

This will result in the following response:

```
{
  ...
  "createdAt": 1534923249,
  ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The `@JsonFormat` annotation seems to be ignored.

Comment: @ShadowMan Does `@JsonFormat` annotation work on other properties of the same class? If not then check if there isn't any custom serializers registered with your mapper.

Comment: fwiw both of these annotations on an Instant variable: `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT, timezone = "UTC")` and `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER, timezone = "UTC")` resulted in this unfortunate format for me:  `1596745072.206033000`

Comment: what's the point of timezone here? Epoch is always from Jan 1 1970 00:00 UTC.

Comment: @ShadowMan Did you manage to sort it out? I'm also still getting the default epoch+nanos object instead.

Comment: @tishma yes I did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51679621/2167531 Basically, you just have to use custom de/serializers, which you can either setup in the `ObjectMapper` or as annotations on the model property.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowMan. I refused to accept implementing anything custom as an option for such an ordinary task. I've succeeded by adding:
`@JsonSerialize(using = InstantSerializer.class)`
along with `shape.NUMBER`. I did get the Decimal result featuring `seconds.nanoseconds`, and I couldn't find a viable option to make the formatter stick to the `epochSeconds`. Since this is a one-off for me - that's just good enough.