# Deserialize millisecond timestamp to java.time.Instant

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, java-time

I'm attempting to read a JSON file using Jackson and store one of the fields that is stored as a epoch milliseconds as a Java `Instant`, however deserialization is not behaving as expected.

Here is what I am seeing when trying to read the timestamp:

> 1503115200000

Jackson is setting the `Instant` field as `+49601-10-28T16:00:00Z`.

This appears to be occurring because Jackson's default is to read the timestamp with `Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long l)` instead of `Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long l)`.

Is there a way to set the Jackson `ObjectMapper` to use the `ofEpochMilli` method instead? This is what I currently have for my `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false)
            .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

**Note**

If I change the input JSON to ISO date such as `2017-08-19T04:00:00Z` or to epoch seconds such as `1503115200` the `Instant` field is able to set properly.

Unfortunately the JSON input must be epoch milliseconds e.g. `1503115200000`.

Comment: I had similar issue, Spring uses Jackson but library with NimbusJwtEncoder uses Gson. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 34):

Solution was to add `.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false)` to the ObjectMapper. Complete ObjectMapper looks like:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false)
            .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false)
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Comment: For more info see [the documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime)

Answer (score 20):

For those who use **Spring Boot** and experience this issue during rest request deserialization - provide this in the application.properties:

`spring.jackson.deserialization.read-date-timestamps-as-nanoseconds=false`

@JB Nizet answer is correct, but since Spring Boot has it's own ObjectMapper inside - you need to configure this value in the properties.

Answer (score 7):

A more flexible solution could be to write your own convertor class, if you don't want to edit or create an object mapper.

```
public class LongToInstantConverter extends StdConverter<Long, Instant> {
    public Instant convert(final Long value) {
        return Instant.ofEpochMilli(value);
    }
}
```

You just need to add the annotation in your class

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter = LongToInstantConverter.class)
private Instant sentDate;
```

Comment: For me, this was a better solution. It limits the impact of the change to only the fields that need the conversion.

Comment: Sadly we cannot always change the serialized object. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

From https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/blob/master/datetime/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.java:

> The more ambiguous integer types are read as fractional seconds without a decimal point if {@code READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS} is enabled (it is by default), and otherwise they are read as milliseconds.

So you need to disable READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS.